# как добавить в текстовый запрос для mySQL переменную id

Tags: java, mysql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как добавить в текстовый запрос для mySQL переменную id

Comment: От банального String.format("DELETE FROM user2 WHERE id=%d;", id); 
И до чего угодно, вариантов и примеров масса.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте `PreparedStatement`:

```
//example
public void insertProduct(String name, int price){
   Connection connection = DriverManager...
   String sql = "INSERT INTO Products (ProductName, Price) Values (?, ?)";
   PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
   preparedStatement.setString(1, name);
   preparedStatement.setInt(2, price);

   preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
}
```

Comment: спасибо огромное !!